# RabbitMq - pika - python - Dropping messages when published

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

```
def get_connection_and_channel(self, connection_parameters):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connection_parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    return (connection, channel)  


connection_parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters( server, port, virtual_host, credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(user_name, password))

connection,channel = self.get_connection_and_channel(connection_parameters)

channel.confirm_delivery()
count=0
for json_string in open(json_file, 'r'):
    result_json = json.loads(json_string)
    message_body = json.dumps(result_json['body'])
    routing_key = result_json['RoutingKey']
    channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.output_exchange_name,routing_key=routing_key,body=message_body.strip())
    count += 1
self.logger.info('Sent %d messages' % count)
connection.close()
```

I am using this code to send out messages to a RabbitMQ server. But once in  a while this is not sending all the messages to the corresponding queue. It's missing random number of messages each time it runs.

I can't understand what's the problem here.

Answer (score 6):

Chances are that your messages are being returned as it couldn't route the message to any existing queue. Try adding a callback in `channel.confirm_delivery`:

```
channel.confirm_delivery(on_delivery_confirmation)

def on_delivery_confirmation(self, method_frame):
        confirmation_type = method_frame.method.NAME.split('.')[1].lower()            
        if confirmation_type == 'ack':
            self.logger.info('message published')
        elif confirmation_type == 'nack':
            self.logger.info('message not routed')
```

If this is the case, then try binding a consumer queue first with the exchange and routing key before publishing the message.

Answer (score 6):

### The simple *(less reliable)* way

First, enable durable queues adding:

```
channel.queue_declare(queue='your_queue', durable=True)
```

**to both, publisher and consumer** *(before doing the publishing/consuming)*.

Then you can be sure your queue won't be lost, even if the RabbitMQ server dies and restarts.

#### The publisher

On the publisher, add `properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2)` to your `basic_publish` call, to make sure your messages are persistent.

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.output_exchange_name,
                      routing_key=routing_key,
                      body=message_body.strip(),
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))
```

That should do the trick to avoid losing _published messages.

#### The consumer

From the consumer point of view, the [official RabbitMQ tutorial for python](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) says:

> In order to make sure a message is never lost, RabbitMQ supports message acknowledgments. An *ack(nowledgement)* is sent back from the consumer to tell RabbitMQ that a particular message had been received, processed and that RabbitMQ is free to delete it. [...] Message acknowledgments are turned on by default.

When you build the consumer, ensure you are sending *ack*
 properly, to let RabbitMQ erase it from the queue.

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print "Received %r" % (body,)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='your_queue')
```

### The truly safe way

If you need a stronger and more reliable method to be totally sure of publishing confirmation relaying on RabbitMQ, you should use the [*plublish confirm*](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) feature of the AMQP protocol.

From [pika documentation](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/blocking_delivery_confirmations.html):

```
import pika

# Open a connection to RabbitMQ on localhost using all default parameters
connection = pika.BlockingConnection()

# Open the channel
channel = connection.channel()

# Declare the queue
channel.queue_declare(queue="test", durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)

# Turn on delivery confirmations
channel.confirm_delivery()

# Send a message
if channel.basic_publish(exchange='test',
                         routing_key='test',
                         body='Hello World!',
                         properties=pika.BasicProperties(content_type='text/plain',
                                                         delivery_mode=1)):
    print 'Message publish was confirmed'
else:
    print 'Message could not be confirmed'
```

So according to your code, I'll use something similar to:

```
count=0
for json_string in open(json_file, 'r'):
    result_json = json.loads(json_string)
    message_body = json.dumps(result_json['body'])
    routing_key = result_json['RoutingKey']
    if channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.output_exchange_name,routing_key=routing_key,body=message_body.strip(),
                             properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2)):  # Make it persistent
        count += 1
    else:
        # Do something with your undelivered message
self.logger.info('Sent %d messages' % count)
connection.close()
```

Or as a *brute-force* approach, you can use a `while` loop instead of an `if` to ensure all of your messages are sent:

```
count = 0
for json_string in open(json_file, 'r'):
    result_json = json.loads(json_string)
    message_body = json.dumps(result_json['body'])
    routing_key = result_json['RoutingKey']
    while not channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.output_exchange_name,
                                    routing_key=routing_key,
                                    body=message_body.strip(),
                                    properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2)):
        pass # Do nothing or even you can count retries
    count += 1
self.logger.info('Sent %d messages' % count)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this to receive only one message with your command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import ujson as json


def receive():
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='raw_post', durable=True)

    method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue='raw_post')

    if method_frame.NAME == 'Basic.GetEmpty':
        connection.close()
        return ''
    else:
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
        connection.close()
        return json.loads(body), method_frame.message_count


a = ''
while a not in ['quit', 'sair', 'exit', 'bye']:
    a = input("whats up?")
    print(receive())
```

just a sender with 5000 messages to queue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import ujson as json

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='raw_post', durable=True)

for i in range(5000):
    info = {"info": "test", "value": i}

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                          routing_key='raw_post',
                          body=json.dumps(info),
                          properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                              delivery_mode=2,  # make message persistent
                          ))

    print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!' {}".format(i))
connection.close()
```